# Which version of .NET standard does .NET Core 2.2 attempt to target?

Tags: .net, .net-core, nuget, .net-standard-2.0, .net-standard-2.1

I have a .NET Core 2.2 application that is referencing a NuGet package that has targets for both .NET Standard 2.0 and 2.1.

i.e.  NuGet package targets

```
<TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;netstandard2.1</TargetFrameworks>
```

This NuGet package is targeting different versions of the DI and Logging NuGet packages depending on the target framework:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" Version="2.2.0" Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'netstandard2.0'" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" Version="3.0.0" Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'netstandard2.1'" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" Version="2.2.0" Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'netstandard2.0'" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" Version="3.0.0" Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'netstandard2.1'" />
```

My .NET Core application is targeting .NET Core 2.2:

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
```

When I look at the NuGet dependencies for the .NET Core 2.2 app, it is pulling in the 3.0.0 versions of the Logging and DI packages.  To me, this indicates that it is trying to use the .NET Standard 2.1 targeted version of the NuGet package.

[image]

How can I force it to use the .NET Standard 2.0 target?

### UPDATE

This appears to be an issue with Visual Studio.  After restarting it, everything started compiling and the errors went away.  However, now when I try to use Entity Framework 3.0 wrapped in precompile directives (`#if NETSTANDARD2_1`), the text is grayed out as if the directive was not defined.  If I try to compile the application, it gives me errors, which are expected since I haven't included the proper `usings`.  These errors don't show up before compilation, though.

Comment: See [.net implementation support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-implementation-support).

Comment: check your package that multi-targets ns2.0.and ns2.1. It's more likely that package's dependencies incorrectly specify the 3.0 version of its dependencies for the ns2.0 tfm, rather than the project that uses your package selecting the wrong assets/dependencies. Looking at the conditions on your `PackageReference`s, I expect `dotnet pack` would create the package correctly, so I'm wondering if you're using a `nuspec` file, rather than letting nuget auto generate one?

Comment: The packages are being packaged correctly with the proper dependency versions. 
 I verified this by unzipping the nupack file in the NuGet cache just to be sure. 
 Ultimately, this appears to be an issue with Visual Studio.  Restarting it fixed the issue.  It seems like VS is locking onto a specific framework and building / showing the error log from that version instead of both.  I wish there were a way to force it to a specific version of the framework.